# Create a csv file in from a python list

Tags: python, list, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

I have a list like the following with the \n separating each new lines

```
['Data,9,record,timestamp,"896018545",s,position_lat,"504719750",semicircles,position_long,"-998493490",semicircles,distance,"10.87",m,altitude,"285.79999999999995",m,speed,"1.773",m/s,unknown,"3929",,unknown,"1002",,enhanced_altitude,"285.79999999999995",m,enhanced_speed,"1.773",m/s,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n', 'Data,9,record,timestamp,"896018560",s,position_lat,"504717676",semicircles,position_long,"-998501870",semicircles,distance,"71.85",m,altitude,"285.0",m,speed,"5.533",m/s,unknown,"3924",,unknown,"1001",,enhanced_altitude,"285.0",m,enhanced_speed,"5.533",m/s,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]
```

This is hard to read, so I need to extract the following out of this list into a CSV file in python in the below format without using pandas:

```
timestamp, position_lat,altitude
"896018545","504719750","285.79999999999995"
"896018560","504717676","285.0"
```

I have the following, but I am confused about how to add the data into the CSV file:

```
header = ['timestamp','latitude','altitude']
with open('target.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)
    # write the data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you need to do is write additional rows that include your data.

```py
...
    ...
    writer.writerow(["896018545","504719750","285.79999999999995"])
    writer.writerow(["896018560","504717676","285.0"])

# alternatively,

data = [["896018545","504719750","285.79999999999995"], 
["896018560","504717676","285.0"]]
...
    ...
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```